# Qt: Re-Implementing dropEvent() for QGroupBox

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

On my GUI I have a QListWidget and I'd like to be able to drag an item out of it and onto a QGroupBox I have nearby.

I've noticed that the dropEvent() function is a virtual function within QWidget - if I want to re-implement that for QGroupBox can I just implement that function alone?

Or do I have to actually subclass QGroupBox to make my own style of widget with a re-implemented dropEvent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass QGroupBox, implement the methods for supporting drag'n drop + use that class instead.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405546

Comment: One could also install an event filter and handle drop events that way, without subclassing.

Comment: I tried the event filter as this is how I handle some mouse over events. For some reason I couldn't get the group box to accept the drop though - I called the setAcceptDrops(true) on it but it still gave me a little warning sign when I dragged over the top of it...

If I can get dropEvent() to work I get the mime data as well which is useful...